# web.config authorization: Allow based on method call?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, security

I'm attempting to retrofit an intranet-only ASP.NET webapp with some rudimentary security.

I have a database table of authorized users, keyed on their AD ID, and I have a method which reads the AD ID from the Request object and matches it against the table.  I would like to use the web.config "authorization" elements to call this function, something like this:

```
<location path="/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow method="checkDatabase()"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I realize this syntax is invalid, but is there an equivalent that functions in this fashion?

Comment: Try to set a custom role for the users that are in that datatabase table and set role based security.

Comment: You can use the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AD membership provider. From MSDN example:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
          System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, 
          PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </providers>
</membership>
```